# Can't get my autoloader to work with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I'm having an issue with my folder structure in combination with my PHP files and their namespaces.

Here's my folder structure:

```
myproject
|
-- entry.php
-- src
    |
    -- IndexController.php
```

My `entry.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function (String $class) {
  $sourcePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src';
  $replaceRootPath = str_replace('myproject\Controllers', $sourcePath, $class);
  $replaceDirectorySeparator = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $replaceRootPath);
  $filePath = $replaceDirectorySeparator . '.php';

  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require($filePath);
  }
});

$indexController = new myproject\Controllers\IndexController;
$result = $indexController->controlSomething('this thing');

print($result);
```

My `src/IndexController.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace myproject\Controllers;

class IndexController
{
  public function controlSomething(string $something): string {
    return $something;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I want a bit of a different folder structure. I would like to go one folder deeper to keep my Controllers somewhere organised. So I want a `Controllers` folder to keep my Controllers there. Changing my folder structure to this:

```
myproject
|
-- entry.php
-- src
    |
    -- Controllers
        |
        -- IndexController.php
```

results in an error saying `Class 'myproject\Controllers\IndexController' not found`.

How can I achieve this? I've tried adding `/Controllers` to the code where paths and namespaces are defined, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Pro tip: don't write your own, but use composer's (https://getcomposer.org/) autoloader

Comment: @Stratadox I was under the impression Composer is only for autoloading third-party packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup, you've mapped the folder `src` to the base namespace `myproject\Controllers`. Whatever comes after `myproject\Controllers`, is expected to mirror a subdirectory structure starting at `src`.

What follows is the following: when you put `IndexController` in the directory `src\Controllers`, the autoloader would only find it if the full class name were `myproject\Controllers\Controllers\IndexController`.

What you probably want to do instead, is map `src` to `myproject` directly, eg.

```
$replaceRootPath = str_replace('myproject', $sourcePath, $class);
```

The solution I tend to favour, and is the current industry standard for php, is to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as autoloader.

Once installed, configuring your autoloader would become as simple as this json segment:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myproject\\": "src"
    }
},
```

And, optionally,

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myproject\\Test\\": "tests"
    }
},
```

Using composer has the additional benefit of being able to pull from a vast collection of open source modules to simplify your life.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very useful. I am already using Composer to use third party packages and didn't know it was common to use Composer to autoload your own namespaces as well. I will give Composer a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

namespace myproject\src\Controllers;
```

Comment: This might work, but it would be somewhat accidental: since "myproject\Controllers" isn't in the namespace, the base directory will not be applied at all. Instead, this autoloader would simply swap the backslashes for slashes.

Comment: Note that I haven't downvoted this answer; maybe I should, but since I posted a "competing" answer I'm hesitant to do so.